# Как получить доступ к функциям переменных : напр: var testString : String = “как”. Здесь после точки должен отображаться функции

Tags: android, kotlin

Как получить доступ к функциям переменных : напр: var testString : String = “как”. Здесь после точки должен отображаться функции

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Может надо сделать так? (Например)

```kotlin
val str : String = "строка"
val len : Integer
len = str.count() //в переменную len записывается длина строки str
```